# subset data based on matrix of row numbers

Tags: r, subset

Say i have the following data

```
B <- (5:20)
C <- (6:21)
D <- (7:22)
E <- (8:23)
data <- data.frame(B,C,D,E)
```

and I also have a matrix of

```
id <- c(4,7,9,12,15)
```

where this matrix represents the row identities I want to output into a new data.frame

How can one use the `subset` function to subset the original data

```
new <- subset(data, .....)
```

so that new only consists of the 5 observations

Comment: Don't use `subset`. It's as simple as `data[id,]`. Study `help("[")`.

Comment: small remark : `id` is not a matrix, it is a vector

Comment: thanks for the advice on what to research @Roland

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
data[id,]
#    B  C  D  E
#4   8  9 10 11
#7  11 12 13 14
#9  13 14 15 16
#12 16 17 18 19
#15 19 20 21 22
```

The syntax `data[i,j]` creates a subset of `data` with row(s) `i` and column(s) `j`